# Ensure the CPU is faulty

Tags: boot, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

Recently, I decided to build a PC for local server & miscellaneous tasks. The configuration is:

- [Gigabyte p35-ds3](https://www.gigabyte.ru/products/page/mb/ga-p35-ds3)
- 2 x 1 Gb RAM (noname, looking same), 2 x 2 Gb RAM (kingston and noname,
  ofc looking different), but all modules are 800 Mhz and has identical
  timings
- [Pentium 4 3.00
  Ghz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/ru/ru/ark/products/27479/intel-pentium-4-processor-631-supporting-ht-technology-2m-cache-3-00-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html)
  *or* [Intel® Core™2 Quad Q9550](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/ru/ru/ark/products/33924/intel-core-2-quad-processor-q9550-12m-cache-2-83-ghz-1333-mhz-fsb.html)
- NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT 256 Mb *or* [Gigabyte GV-N430-1GI](https://www.gigabyte.com/ru/Graphics-Card/GV-N430-1GI-rev-20)
- HDD is present, but irrelevant
- PSU Finepower DNP-350 (300 W) *or* noname 400 W.

So, first of all, I know that this build is slightly outdated. Motherboard + CPU + two sticks of RAM were stored for a long time together in-house and does not have visible problems. Configuration of MB + Pentium 4 + all RAM sticks + any GPU boots successfully and operates. Okay. 
However, I decided to upgrade, so bought another 4 GB of ram and ordered the Q9550 from one of the famous online shops. It was listed as "used, working". So, after I installed it, system booted, I installed Lubuntu 20.04, rebooted few times and so on. The next day and the day after PC booted successfully. However, today it did not boot. When the power button is pressed, fans start and very soon stop, power led switches off too. Without any further actions, in a few seconds PC turns on again, now, the fans are rotating, HDD (if connected) spins up, but nothing on the monitor, no beeps. I tried another PSU, another GPU and 4 or 5 RAM combinations, the same outcome. In this configuration, I could pull out GPU and RAM, still no beeps. If the 4-pin CPU connector is disconnected, CPU cooler fan rotates much faster, I believe at the maximal speed. 
In the end, I replaced the CPU with Pentium 4 and everything works smoothly, at least for couple of hours and 5 reboots. 
I understand that the culprit is the CPU, but the question is: is it CPU problem alone or combination of components, e.g. incompatibility with MB or too weak PSU? Or even the MB is deteriorating? Maybe I simply need to perform some actions, like change jumper position?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it was faulty BIOS. Loading defaults and CMOS jumper-clearing were useless. However, reflashing BIOS with the exactly same version (F12 for this mobo) immediately resolved the problem. I don't know exactly what was the reason behind, but I can guess that reflashing clears more "settings" than defaulting/clearing. As a fantastic scenario, BIOS code went into a corrupted state just because it was not powered for >10 years or whatever.
Now everything works fine using any valid combination of HW listed above.

Comment: Read up on flash memory tech - flash content can get corrupted with time, just as you experienced.